# JS O que tá errado nesse codigo?

Tags: javascript

Uma loja virtual permite a seus visitantes filtrar produtos pelo preço. Existe um array com os preços dos produtos. Um programador já criou uma função `maisBaratosQue(valor, precos)` que retorna um array com os preços dos produtos mais baratos que o valor passado como parâmetro. Outro programador já criou uma função `maisCarosQue(valor, precos)` que retorna um array com os preços mais caros que o valor passado como parâmetro. Chegou sua vez!

Crie uma função `precosEntre(valorMenor, valorMaior, precos)` que deve utilizar as funções `maisBaratosQue` e `maisCarosQue` para retornar os preços que estão entre o `valorMenor` e o `valorMaior`. Sua função deve receber então dois parâmetros:

- `valorMenor` para representar o valor mínimo dos preços a serem listados
- `valorMaior` para representar o valor máximo dos preços a serem listados
- `precos` para representar um array com os preços dos produtos

Ela deve retornar um array com todos os preços entre `valorMenor` e `valorMaior`

```
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
   return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}
 
function maisCarosQue(valor, precos){
   return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}
function precosEntre(valorMaior, valorMenor, precos) {
  precos.filter( maisBaratosQue() && maisCarosQue(), valor);
     return precosEntre;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`maisBaratosQue` e `maisCarosQue` retornam arrays, não sendo possível fazer `precos.filter( maisBaratosQue() && maisCarosQue(), valor)`.

Dadas as retrições apresentadas, para implementar este método é necessário filtrar a lista uma vez com cada um dos métodos anteriores. Algo como:

```js
function precosEntre(valorMaior, valorMenor, precos) {
    var precosEntre = maisBaratosQue(valorMaior, precos);
    precosEntre = maisCarosQue(valorMenor, precosEntre);
  
    return precosEntre;
}
```

Note que a `precosEntre` retornado por `maisBaratosQue` é enviado para `maisCarosQue`.
Cabe também ressaltar que a ordem dos parâmetros de `precosEntre` parece trocada. Geralmente faz-se o menor e depois o maior valor.

```js
function maisBaratosQue(valor, precos) {
    return precos.filter(p => p <= valor);
}
 
function maisCarosQue(valor, precos){
    return precos.filter(p => p >= valor);
}

function precosEntre(valorMaior, valorMenor, precos) {
    var precosEntre = maisBaratosQue(valorMaior, precos);
    precosEntre = maisCarosQue(valorMenor, precosEntre);
  
    return precosEntre;
}

var precos = [1, 11, 15, 22];
var precosEntre = precosEntre(20, 10, precos);

console.log(precosEntre);
```